# Angular passing data to variable and that variable usage

Tags: angular, variables, initialization, ngoninit

Declaring variable

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
testVar:string;
```

then initialising

```
ngOnInit() {

this.somefunction works.subscribe( 
this.testVar='testData';
console.log('log1 '+this.testVar);
);
console.log('log2 '+this.testVar);
}
```

now firing AfterViewInit:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
console.log('log3 '+this.testVar);
```

The results are

```
log1 testData
log2 undefined
log3 undefined
```

question is why log2 and log 3 give undefined testVar and how can I fix that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how asynchronous data works. The variables are not assigned values as soon the call is made. All statements that directly depend on an async data (`this.testVar` here) should be inside the subscription.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.someFunction().subscribe(
    value => {
      this.testVar='testData';
      console.log('log1 '+this.testVar);
      console.log('log2 '+this.testVar);
      ...
    }
  );
}
```

[`AfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) lifecycle hook has nothing to do with how the variables are initialized in the controller. It will be called after Angular has fully initialized a component's view/template.

See here for more details on how to access async data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921